# Divide string with # length equally

Tags: javascript

I have a string `1234567890`.

I'd like to divide it every `4` characters or `n`.

**It has to be divided start from the end of string**

With above case, It would be `["12", "3456", "7890"]`.

`123` => `["123"]`

`12345` => `["1","2345"]`

I found some similar answer from here and I edited but it doesn't work.

```js
function getChunks(number, size) {
  let str = number.toString(),
      length = str.length - size + 1;
      
  return Array.from({ length }, (_,i) => +str.slice(i*size, (i*size) + size))
}

console.log(getChunks(1234,4));
console.log(getChunks(12345,4));
console.log(getChunks(123,4));
console.log(getChunks(1234567890,4));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution could be as follows:

- You can use [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) with an index of `-4` to get the last 4 characters of a string.
- Update your original string, `str`, to remove the last four characters, using `str.slice(0,-4)`.
- Repeat the same steps until `str.length` is `0`. The last `str` in the loop can be less than 4 characters long and it won't affect the use of `String.prototype.slice()`.
- Finally, use [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to reorder the array properly.

```js
let str = "1234567890";
let segments = [];

while (str.length) {
  segments.push(str.slice(-4));
  str = str.slice(0, -4);
}
segments.reverse();
console.log(segments);
```

Comment: . How is it so simple!?

Comment: @zynkn If you do this a lot over a long period of time, you get used to doing things like this with little effort. Practice makes perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

To correct your initial code, there are two problems with it.

1. The derived length of the new array is wrong - `str.length - size + 1` will give you the wrong result. Assuming `str.length === 10` and `size = 4`, then that would be `10 - 4 + 1` which gives you `7`.

   - The actual length should be how many times you can fit `size` into `str.length`. You also need to round up. So, `str.length === 8` and `size === 4` would result in `2`, while `str.length === 10` and `size === 4` is `3`.
   - The formula is `Math.ceil(str.length / size)`
2. The chunking done with `str.slice(i*size, (i*size) + size)` tries to make the first groups as big as possible, and the last might be smaller. Whereas, you need the *opposite* effect - the last groups should be as small as possible, the first one would just have enough items to fit whatever is left.

   - The way to determine "what is left" is using [the remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder), for example, `10 % 4 === 2`. So, the first group has to be of two items. Since this determines the *size* of the group, this means that it has to be accounted for as an offset to both the start and end indexes. Unfortunately, that makes the formula very annoying to derive - you need a *maximum* difference of `size` and a *minimum* difference of `remainder`. First start should always be `0`, the first end `remainder`, then each following iteration, you need add `size` to both the start and end. However, the first *and second* `start` index can be less than `size`. As I said, annoying, so the formula you want is
   - `start = Math.max(0, size*(i - 1) + remainder)` - you *could* go negative, for `i = 0` but you clamp it to a minimum of zero. The second iteration you'd start from `remainder`. So the progression is `0 -> remainder -> remainder + size -> remainder + size + size` and so on.
   - `end = remainder + size * i` - add `remainder` as offset and only increase by `size` each time. The progression is `remainder -> remainder + size -> remainder + size + size` etc.
   - `remainder = (str.length % size) || size` - pretty important but left it for last. I think it makes more sense once you know how `start` and `end` work. This definition of `remainder` solves problems with what happens if `str.length` is perfectly divisible by `size`. Without using `size` instead of `0`, you get problems with `str.length === 4` and `size === 4` the `end` formula would give us `0`. So, in other words, hence we have to define it as `0 > remainder >= size`.

All this produces the corrected version:

```js
function getChunks(number, size) {
  let str = number.toString(),
      length = Math.ceil(str.length / size);
      
  let remainder = (str.length % size) || size;
  return Array.from({ length }, (_,i) => {
    let start = Math.max(0, size*(i - 1) + remainder);
    let end = remainder + size * i;
  
    return +str.slice(
      start, 
      end
    )
  })
}

console.log(getChunks(1234,4));
console.log(getChunks(12345,4));
console.log(getChunks(12345678,4));
console.log(getChunks(123,4));
console.log(getChunks(1234567890,4));
```

I just wanted to show what the original version would look like if it worked. I wouldn't honestly recommend it, as it's not easy to read. There are ways to re-arrange the formulas but it's overall still not very intuitive.

Comment: Wow, It looks like a Thesis. I will read and try to understand it. Thank you very much.